# Let's get critical: Aug 2014 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Arduino Stack Exchange](http://arduino.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Final Results

- [MCU Type ATmega16U2 not avaliable in Eclipse AVR Plugin](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/3440/mcu-type-atmega16u2-not-avaliable-in-eclipse-avr-plugin)

**Net Score: 6** (Excellent: 6, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [How to use two Sonar's](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/3424/how-to-use-two-sonars)

**Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [What is the frequency of PWM output on Arduino](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/3182/what-is-the-frequency-of-pwm-output-on-arduino)

**Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Is programming the ATTiny85 possible in 1.5?](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/3345/is-programming-the-attiny85-possible-in-1-5)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Disable Boot Flash completely on ATMega](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/3294/disable-boot-flash-completely-on-atmega)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [How can I make my Arduino code work?](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/3203/how-can-i-make-my-arduino-code-work)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [nRF24L01+ (RF24) radio with Arduino Micro](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/nrf24l01-rf24-radio-with-arduino-micro)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Arduino UNO USB not recognized](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/3357/arduino-uno-usb-not-recognized)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Can I control analog IO pins using Yun Linux](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/3422/can-i-control-analog-io-pins-using-yun-linux)

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 3)

---

- [Need some help with controlling a fan through PWM](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/3164/need-some-help-with-controlling-a-fan-through-pwm)

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

Comment: Nice eval, everyone!

Answer (score 2):

**First impressions:**

*Positive:*

- We have a lot of great answers that provide useful information.
- For some questions, I could use basic search terms for a subject and see *our site* as the second or third item on the list.

*Negative:*

- I noticed that the quality of the questions could be improved. We don't have a lot of edits
- Our tagging could be improved. For example, a lot of scenarios there is either no board tag or there are *multiple* board tags when the question only relates to one board. Plus, there are some questions that only use the tag "Arduino-Uno"

*Other thoughts:*

- Although this isn't directly related to the quality of the site, I noticed that a lot of questions were hard to find online because they were primarily code based, thus it is very hard to have an identical situation. I think this is just a flaw in the SE benchmark system, not with out site quality.

Other than that, I thought most of the questions selected were quality. I do think we need to have more users working to edit, close, and retag questions to improve the general grammatical elements and the appearance of the content. We might have to establish better tagging guidelines (using meta).

*What can you do?*

- If you see a bad question, **edit it**. If the tags are wrong, **retag it!** (If you don't have 2K to do this, try doing something else with the post or just leave it).
- If you're not sure what should be done but know that it isn't right, **don't be afraid to ask in chat or in meta**. Meta is the foundation that allows the rest of the site to grow.